# Completely deleting all resources related to AWS Glue and AWS Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-billing, aws-data-pipeline

I'm a student getting started with AWS (free tier).

After realizing (I got billed) that I've exhausted my free tier for AWS Glue and Data Pipeline. I deleted all the resources that were billing me, even these two s3-buckets (mentioned in an image below).
Even after deleting everything these 2 buckets keeps popping up.

How can I delete all the AWS Glue and Data Pipeline related services?
Because I'm still getting billed even though I'm not using any resources.

[image: s3-bucket-list-snapshot]

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "these 2 buckets keeps popping up"? Popping out where?

Comment: @Marcin in s3-bucket list. Though on clicking on it, it shows the message that "bucket not found "

Comment: Do you have any glue job running on schedule?

Comment: @Marcin no i've deleted all the resources

Comment: Maybe you have something in other regions generating these buckets?

Comment: I did everything in the same region (us-east-1).